# Where in Handbridge is / was the Rook or Rock?

Tags: england, census-records, historical-gazetteer, place-names, cheshire

On the 1841 census, Frances Potter was living in Handbridge, Chester, and the place is listed as "Rook" or "Rock". I have been to Handbridge many times but have never come across this place before.

Can you help me locate this place?

[image: 1841 Census record for Frances Potter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]It's where the CoOp/petrol station is today right in the heart of Handbridge.

Answer (score 7):

If you consult the enumerators schedule associated with this piece, you will find a description of the area covered. In this case, the piece includes (I may have made transcription errors):

> All that part of the Parish of Saint Mary on the Hill extending from
>   the Hare & Hounds Public House to the West End of the Bottoms Lane
>   comprising all the Dwelling Houses situate in the Old Wrexham Road on
>   the South and South East sides of Handbridge the entire of Eaton Road
>   Heron Bridge Belgrave Square the Rook and terminating at the West End
>   of the Bottoms Lane aforesaid.

If you know the area that should give you some idea where to look on an old map, such as the ones at the [National Library of Scotland](https://maps.nls.uk/)

For the 1841 census, the tithe maps made shortly before then are an excellent reference point. The [Cheshire tithe maps](https://maps.cheshireeast.gov.uk/tithemaps/) are online and free and clearly show "Rocks" at the west end of Bottoms Lane (search by location for Handbridge Chester) and zoom in. If you click on plot 275 you will find Francis Potter as one of the inhabitants.

Comment: These tithe maps are great. Never knew about them before but will certainly be using them from now on.